# Angularjs select chosen not support translate

Tags: angularjs, html

```html
<select chosen
        options="myOptions"
        ng-model="StatCode"
        data-placeholder="{{'PleaseSelect' | translate}}"
        ng-options="item[0] as item[1] + ' / ' + item[0] for item in myOptions"
        required></select>
```

I changed language. But don't change placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `placeholder-text-single` for `single select` and `placeholder-text-multiple` for `multiple select`

Also your expression should be enclosed in `''` as

`placeholder-text-single="'{{'PleaseSelect' | translate}}'"`

*Notice the single quote before `{{` and after `}}`*

Here is a basic example which translates `select` `placeholder` and `option text` from English to Russian language.

Usually while converting from one language to another only the `option text`changes whereas its `option value` remains same irrespective of the language

**[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/snzecjyz/7/)**

Click on the hyperlinks to see the language change.